# Definine Spyder coding utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Due to a problem I had, all stange symbols such as à, ç... have changed to Ã or Ã§ (all these no-ascii characters). This is happening every time I save a file in Spyder and I would want to know where can I cahange the encoding to utf-8 (the encoding when saving a file).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default encoding to utf by code:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

This is not recommended by many users, so try changing `PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"` in your environment first.

Comment: Hi, do you know how to change the coding in an envorinment?

Comment: Try # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the very top of your script. I've never worked with Spyder, so I can't guarantee you that it is right. But give it a try :) Edit: With a star * between the two dashes. It won't display here.